# Chrome mobile annoying popup to open Android app intent

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, android-intent, chrome-custom-tabs

Let's assume we have installed Android app in the mobile phone with intent filter scheme `android-app-scheme` and some registered host with path pattern in data of intent filter.

If we use this code in webpage for the Android Chrome:

```
   addEventListener("load", (event) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              window.location.href = "android-app-scheme://some/url/intent"
            }, 5000);
    });
```

Annoying popup will appear to ask permission to open the app ("this website wants to open the ... app"):

[image]

Interestingly if we just use direct link for example `<a href="android-app-scheme://some/url/intent">Open App</a>`

And user will click explicitly the link then no popup will appear and app will launch straightaway.

Is there any way to avoid this popup without asking user about explicit click?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're encountering with deep links on Android Chrome is due to security measures implemented by the browser. Unfortunately, there isn't a direct way to bypass the permission prompt without user interaction.

However, you can implement a workaround:

- Providing a button or explicit link that users can click to initiate
  the redirection, thereby avoiding the permission prompt.
- Alternatively, you can return a 301 redirect request from the backend
  directly, which essentially triggers the deep link through
  server-side redirection, bypassing the need for user interaction.

See: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/intents#considerations